# How to design React component that is not re-used often?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, file-structure

I'm working on a web app with React, and I'm not sure how to / whether to extract these components. I want to discuss my Header component with a file structure that looks like this:

[image]

In my Header component, I currently render this:

```
<header>
  <Logo />
  <Navigation />
</header>
```

With my Navigation component looking like this:

```
<nav>
  <Links />
  <Account />
</nav>
```

It's not very flexible / reusable. I could also render everything directly into the Header component:

```
<header>
   <img />
   <nav>
      <a>Blog</a>
      <a>Socials</a>
      <button>Sign in</button>
   </nav>
</header>
```

What approach should I pick? Why should I extract these components, if they are not really going to be re-used in a website ( there is only 1 header )?

**I'm looking for some advice on how to tackle components with limited logic and quite some nesting in React which are not really used twice in an application ( and how to handle the file structure ).**

I understand that extracting a component is useful when you have a lot of logic surrounding it, but my logic is going to be very basic, just some conditional styling.

*By the way, I'm using `styled-components` and these `styles.ts` files just export styled elements*

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you could start with a single components styling the header and its children. Later on, if you find yourself adding to (e.g.) the nav and feel like it's becoming harder to manage in a single component, isolate the nav and its styles.

Comment: Voted to close as too opinion based. However, my opinion is that if your components are so simple that they are basically just one or two HTML elements, just put them all in the Header rather than breaking them into subcomponents. There is no one true solution, but you should try to find the balance between 1.) component re-use, 2.) logical units that work in isolation, 3.) maintainability. Finding that balance is part of becoming an experienced developer.